При запуске webdriver Chrome selenium браузер закрывается через секунду после запуска
Вот код скрипта. Специально написал процедуру открытия firefox через selenium - всё работает, но не работает с драйвером Chrome. Браузер открывается и сразу закрывается
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chrome_driver_path = r"d:\_bin\_selenium\_chrome\chromedriver.exe"
firefox_driver_path = r"d:\_bin\_selenium\_firefox\geckodriver.exe"

def start_firefox_with_profile():
    # Указываем путь к драйверу, если он не добавлен в PATH
    service = Service(executable_path=firefox_driver_path)
    # Инициализация Firefox через Selenium
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    return driver
def start_chrome_with_profile(profile_path, driver_path):
    # Проверяем, существует ли директория профиля
    if not os.path.exists(profile_path):
        raise Exception(f"Директория профиля {profile_path} не существует")
    # Настройка ChromeOptions
    chrome_options = Options()
    # Указываем директорию профиля Chrome
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={profile_path}")
    # Указываем путь к драйверу Chrome
    service = Service(driver_path)
    # Инициализируем драйвер Chrome с профилем
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver

def main():
    # Укажите путь к профилю Chrome
    profile_directory = r"c:\_br\_prog"
    # Укажите путь к драйверу ChromeDriver
    chrome_driver_path = r"d:\_bin\_selenium\_chrome\chromedriver.exe"
    # Запускаем Chrome с указанным профилем
    try:
        driver = start_chrome_with_profile(profile_directory, chrome_driver_path)
        #driver = start_firefox_with_profile()
        # Открываем сайт для проверки
        # driver.get("https://www.ya.ru")
        # Закрываем браузер через 10 секунд
        # driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        # driver.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Вот видео с экрана как это происходит
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Lm-vFQYYHPGKjA
И да - браузер закрывается после запуска, без использования метода get
